# Cant host bootstrap and glyphicons on Amazon S3. Cross-Origin Request Blocked.

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

I have a bucket on Amazon S3. In the bucket I have this:

> assets/css/bootstrap.css
>
> assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
>
> assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
>
> assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

Just as the Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use) suggests. However I can't see the glyphicons on my site, instead I get this errors on the console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://bootstrapvitality.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:3): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: https://bootstrapvitality.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

For each glyphicon file.
How can I solve this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=enable+CORS+on+amazon+s3

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Bootstrap CDN.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to Permissions/Edit CORS Configuration solved it:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
```